# Mate doesn't load environment variable when using menu launcher

Tags: shell-script, centos, environment-variables, mate-desktop

I'm using many environment variables to setup several softwares, like maya / nuke, houdini... those variables are refering to other variables.

to set them, I have created scripts in /etc/profile.d/ to set them for all user at once. scripts contains rows like

```
export VARIABLE1=$VARIABLE1:$GENERALVAR/myoptions
```

All was working fine in Gnome3 but this desktop is too slow and heavy, so I have switched to MATE

With MATE, when I click on "application" then the icon of an app, the software start without taking in count any of my environment variable
When I start the same app from terminal, all variable are loaded normally so the variables works

what I have tried :

- put variables in /etc/environment - not working because it doesn't manage script, only text. Not usable in my config
- point the variable script in .desktop file - not handy at all, boring to update, not working that well as I have many variable for each software

how can I make Mate application menu to take in count my variables ?

**EDIT :**

using the menu editor, I have set an app as a terminal application, to make it launch through a terminal
the application start but no variable are take in count 
I reallised that some variable works and others don't, from the exact same .sh script

in pipe.sh :

```
export PIPE_TOOL=/mnt/Pipeline #work
```

in nuke.sh :

```
export NUKE_LIC=1234@server #work 
export NUKE_PATH=$PIPE_TOOL/Nuke #not working under MATE - return /Nuke in the app
export NUKE_GIZMO=$PIPE_TOOL/Gizmo #not working under MATE - return /Gizmo in the app
```

I'm using Centos 7.6 with Mate 1.16.2

thank you

Comment: Adding environment variable definitions to a file ending in .sh in /etc/profile.d/ should show up in the MATE environment too, something else must be happening. Since you are being really vague about the changes you are making and the executable you are running, it’s hard to know what could be wrong.

Comment: hi, 
as said, i use those applications : maya, nuke and houdini.
sh files are constructed like this one `#!/bin/sh
export PIPE_PATH=/mnt/Pipeline`

then an other sh script can be 
`#!/bin/sh
export NUKE_PATH=$PIPE_PATH/Nuke`
no other configuration than that

Comment: If you open a terminal, do you see $PIPE_PATH defined as you expected?

Comment: yes, i can see all variable as expected from terminal but open apps from application launcher dont take them in count. I really don't understand how it's possible

Comment: I suggest you debug how the application launcher runs, there is probably a typo in it, or you’re initializing the variable someplace in the launcher

Comment: Hi, I have tried to see in /usr/share/applications/maya.desktop, for example
it's the exact same file as in gnome (where it work) and nothing seems to be broken

Comment: i have edited my post to give new infos

Comment: Files in /etc/profile.d are sources in alphabetical order. nuke.sh is being evaluated before pipe.sh.  Something in gnome must be running a second login shell making it evaluate them a second time fixing the nuke.sh vars. Try making pipe sort earlier than nuke.

Comment: I have also tried it with renaming pipe.sh to a_pipe.sh but still not working
I have found a fix for now with merging all in a single file. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging all variable to a single script fixed the problem for now